# Perl Using Foreign Characters in Windows

Tags: perl, file, utf-8

I'm trying to print characters like ş,ı,ö,ç in Turkish language in Windows using perl but I couldn't do it. My main purpose is creating folders using special characters in Windows.

This is my code:

```
    use Text::Iconv;
    use strict;
   use warnings;
    $conve = Text::Iconv->new("windows-1254","UTF-16");
    $converted = $conve->convert("ş");
    print $converted;
    system("mkdir $converted");
```

I get a malformed utf-8 character (byte 0xfe) aa.pl at line 7

Comment: What you get as output? Include `use strict; use warnings; use utf8;` too, your code has UTF-8 chars in source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the following as UTF-8:

```
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;
use open ":std", ":encoding(cp1254)";  # Set encoding for STD*
use Encode qw( encode );

my $file_name = "ş";
print "$file_name\n";
system(encode('cp1254', qq{mkdir "$file_name"}));
```

`use utf8` tells Perl the source is UTF-8.

`use open ":std", ":encoding(cp1254)";` causes text sent to STDOUT and STDERR to be encoded using cp1254, and it causes text read from STDIN to be decoded from cp1254.

It doesn't affect what is sent to sustem calls like `system`, so you need to encode those explicitly.

Comment: Thank you also how i can print string using basic perl print or use character in variable

Comment: @Anon Sr, Both are those are being done in the code that's already there.